# Why do apps on the Google Play Store have com. at the start?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

When you get an app from the play store, the apps are always given in this format (For example):

`play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.king.candycrushsaga`

I'm not interested in the main URL, and just the app name, so I get:

```
com.king.candycrushsaga
```

I know that this is the actual app name, that is not the friendly name shown on the app drawer or in the play store, but the `com.` part always confused me. I know what the other parts of the name are for (`com.PublisherName.AppName`), but what is the point of the `com.` at the start?

Comment: It's not always a "`com.`", see https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.projectmaxs.main or https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.nationalrail.google for a couple of examples of something else being there

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The naming convention is derived from the [Java standards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/packages.html#7.7), and is comparable to an URL, but in reverse. The key here is that it has to be unique, that's why it's so specific.

In you example, `com` is the main category which is comparable to a Top Level Domain, which can also be `com`. Next is the company name `king`, which can be compared to a domain name, and finally `candycrushsaga`, which could be a subdomain. Since the names have to be unique, this naming schema is quite usual, but can sometimes be divided even further by adding a subproject name to the end. For example King could separate games from other apps they've created by using the name `com.king.games.candycrushsaga`.

According to Java standards, the first component has to be a valid top level domain (com, net, edu, gov, country-specific), but I remember also seeing package names that didn't respect the standard.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I think I get it now - if my site is `GeorgesApps.com` for example and I make a game called `Ask Your Friends` then it would be `com.GeorgesApps.AskYourFriends`

Comment: Yep
, that's it

Comment: @GeorgeH but then, in lowercase: `com.georgesapps.askyourfriends`.

Comment: Ok, I was just doing that to make it clearer - thanks for the info though!

Comment: @Onik I think it's also worth noting that it's very bad practice to use an URL that you don't own as your package name. That's why apps by King will start `com.king`, which is their domain name. This is the only reason the first part of the package name should be a valid internet TLD.

Comment: @DanHulme. I'm not an app developer, and I don't own a domain name - I was just curious to know why apps were named in that way. I don't have the time to develop apps, or £25 to post it on the play store! :D

Comment: @GeorgeH I understand. The point is, it's not just `com.publishername`, and the choice of `com` isn't arbitrary: it actually ought to be a domain the publisher owns. I didn't think that was clear in onik's answer.